# How to resign a search bar as a first responder without selecting table view's cells?

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, uisearchbar

I have a table view with a search bar on top of it. I would like to implement the following behaviour: when the search bar is tapped and then a user taps anywhere else, the search bar resigns of being a first responder (keyboard is hidden), but at the same time, cells of the table view are not getting selected. I don't use another view for searching. Here is how my table view with a search bar looks like (I know, there is a problem with separators of a table view when I run my project on a simulator. Can't figure out why):

[image]

Currently, when I tap somewhere else, search bar resigns of being the first responder, but the problem is, the cells are getting selected, too. That would be ok, but sometimes, when I have more complex cells (not like the ones in the image), the transition between views is not very smooth. If you know a way how to make the transition smooth, that would be ok, too, or, I would appreciate any suggestion about implementing the behaviour, described above.

Comment: Are you tried with the swipe gesture? A single swipe down to dismiss

Comment: Open simulator in full screen (full scale). It is not an issue as separator is not there!

Comment: @Lion, I did. When I scroll, some separators appear while others, disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way of doing this is to properly implement your tableView `didSelectRow` delegate method.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if searchBar.isFirstResponder {
        searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)
        return
    }

    // perform your actions (present/push controller, etc.)
}
```

If you try to test your application on real device, you will see, that there is no problems with separators in tableView. It's just simulator issue:)

Comment: Yeah, I know that separators behave them like that only on a simulator. It just sucks that sometimes I think I'm the only one who have such problem with them)

Comment: It doesn't work. The transition still gets called. I also tried to check that the search bar is not a first responder in `prepare(for:sender:)` method using an `if` statement, but it anyway gets called.

Comment: if you are setting `Triggered Segues` in Storyboard, then that can be the case. Open it, remove segue from cell and manually perform it after the if statement in `didSelectRowAt` method (call `performSegue` with proper segue identifier)

Comment: Glad it helped :)
Have a nice day!

Answer (score 2):

Put a `UITapGestureRecognizer` over your table view to respond to taps.

Set the tap recognizer to disabled by default.

```
tapRecognizer.isEnabled = false
```

When the search bar becomes active, re-enable the tap recognizer.

```
tapRecognizer.isEnabled = false
```

When it recognizes a tap, dismiss the keyboard by resigning the first responder of the search bar. Also make sure to disable the tap recognizer so you can select the table view cells as usual.

```
@objc private func handleTap(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    recognizer.isEnabled = false
}
```

Comment: Should I add the `UITapGestureRecognizer` to a table view itself or to a view controller? When I add it to a VC, and do as you said, it still selects the row. Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: @TigranIskandaryan Try adding it to the table view. If that does not work, you can create a new view above the table view with the same frame as the table view. Set it's background color to `.clear` and add the recognizer to that view.

Comment: I've tried but without a result. I think your solution would work if I had a `UIViewController`, but unfortunately I have a `UITableViewController`. It doesn't allow me to add a view on top of the table view (well, it adds but doesn't allow me to set constraints) as well as the table view.

Comment: I would suggest refactoring the table view controller to be a child view controller of a `UIViewController`. If you are using the storyboard, this can be done with a container view. You could also consider adding the view in code.

Comment: I would do that, but I have a quite heavily built project (not the one on the image above), so it is quite hard to do.

Comment: @TigranIskandaryan I don't know the details of your project, but neither of the options listed above should require major refactoring. If you decide this table view needs additional features in the future, the refactoring will pay off. My answer works as a solution to the general question. Good luck with your app!